# Continuously connecting to a server via a Socket until a connection is established

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client that I want to try to continuously connect to a server until a connection is established (i.e. until I start the server).

```
clientSocket = new Socket();
while (!clientSocket.isConnected()) {
    try {
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, serverPort));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // sleep prevents a billion SocketExceptions from being printed,
    // and hopefully stops the server from thinking it's getting DOS'd
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After the first attempt, I get a `ConnectionException`; expected, since there is nothing to connect to. After that, however, I start getting `SocketException: Socket closed` which doesn't make sense to me since `clientSocket.isClosed()` always returns false, before and after the `connect()` call.

How should I change my code to get the functionality I need?

Comment: Move your `new Socket` into the retry loop. Don't reuse a broken instance.

Comment: oh my goodness, thank you so much. I've been pulling out my hair over this for far too long. Just proves that the simplicity of a solution is inversely proportional to how frustrating it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reconnect a `Socket`, even if the connect attempt failed. You have to close it and create a new one.